# How to remove random item from array and then remove it from array until array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to remove a random item from an array until the array is empty using jquery or javascript. I need to console out each time the random item.
Basically i am going to create an element with a random image from the given array until all images have been created.

Here is my attempt for getting the random item and removing from array but it it does not go through the entire array-I am stumped.

```
"load": function(){
    var imgArray = ['brain', 'mitochondria', 'microsope', 'beaker', 'beaker-2', 'scientist', 'cell', 'atom', 'dropper'];
    function randomItem(array){
        var arrayLength = array.length+1;
        console.log(arrayLength);
        for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
            var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
            array.pop(item);
            console.log(array);
        }
    }
    randomItem(imgArray);
},
```

Here is my console output:

```
10
home.js:12 ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2", "scientist", "cell", "atom"]
home.js:12 ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2", "scientist", "cell"]
home.js:12 ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2", "scientist"]
home.js:12 ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2"]
home.js:12 ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker"]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The function, [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) will remove an element from the last. So at this context, you have to use [`Array.prototype.splice(indext,cnt)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript),

```
for(var i = array.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length), 1);
  console.log(array);
}
```

And since we are altering the array, we have to traverse it in reverse way, so that the index will not be collapsed.

Comment: thank you so much! Definitely will be diving more into the documentation on arrays.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 13):

Just make a random index and splice while length is greater than zero.

```js
var data = ["brain", "mitochondria", "microsope", "beaker", "beaker-2", "scientist", "cell", "atom"];

while (data.length) {
    document.write(data.splice(data.length * Math.random() | 0, 1)[0] + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the other option. I didn't think about using the while loop as that makes plenty of sense now that i think about it.

Answer (score 6):

[Array.prototype.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from the array, not a specific element. To remove an element at a specific index you can use [Array.prototype.splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) (See: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) ).

You also have a problem with `for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i++)`, since `array.length` changes whenever you remove an item, you'll only get through half the array, you can either loop in reverse `for ( var i = array.length; i--; )`, so that `array.length` is only evaluated once, before the first iteration, or you can use a while loop `while( array.length )`.

Change your loop to:

```
while( array.length ) {
    var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*array.length );
    console.log( array[index] ); // Log the item
    array.splice( index, 1 ); // Remove the item from the array
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I was just telling Nina that a while loop would be the better option for the functionality i am looking for.

Comment: Just saw your update, thank you for the explanation. Never thought about looping in reverse. Have not had to mess with arrays in a while but i obviously need to read back into them as i am lacking in knowledge.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller You could also loop forward like you are used to, but put the array length in a variable first: `var numItems = array.length;` then `for(var i = 0;i<numItems;i++){`, because `array.length` changes when you remove elements but the variable won't be affected.